# Disable location updates from GPS

Tags: android, gps, location, locationlistener

**UPDATED QUESTION - STILL NOT WORKING**

I've changed the code.

Now, deactivateAlerts and activateAlerts are in the MainActivity.

Now, inside activateAlerts(), I'm instantiating a GPSListener for the GPS Provider:

```
if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
    gpsListener = new GPSListener(getApplicationContext());
} else if
```

Where the GPSListener is this:

```
public class GPSListener implements LocationListener {

private Context mCtx;
private Location cLoc;
private LocationManager mLocMan;

public GPSListener (Context ctx){
    mCtx = ctx;
    mLocMan = (LocationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

public Location getLocation()
{
    cLoc = mLocMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    return cLoc;
}

public void stop()
{
    mLocMan.removeUpdates(GPSListener.this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i("UPDATING", "updating location");
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

}
```

}

With the deactiveAlerts() function, I execute the instruction to remove the GPS updates:

```
if(gpsListener!=null){
   gpsListener.stop();
}
```

But the GPS is not stopping yet =(

What is the problem now?

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

The user can activate or deactivate location updates.

If the location updates are activated, it works ok, but when the location updates are deactivated, the GPS is still waiting for updates (and the icon appears on the action bar).

The code is that:

```
public class Alerts extends Fragment {

MyLocationListener myLocationListener = null;

...

public void activateAlerts() {

    locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        Utils.MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE,
                        Utils.MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE,
                        myLocationListener
                );
            } else if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        Utils.MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE,
                        Utils.MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE,
                        myLocationListener
                );
            } else {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER,
                        Utils.MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE,
                        Utils.MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE,
                        myLocationListener
                );
            }
        }
    });

    ...

}

public void deactivateAlerts() {

    ...

    locationManager = (LocationManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if(myLocationListener != null) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
        myLocationListener = null;
    }

    ...
}

public class MyLocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("UPDATING", "updating location");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
        Log.v("LocationListener", "onStatusChanged");
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Log.v("LocationListener", "onProviderDisabled");
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Log.v("LocationListener", "onProviderEnabled");
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

I've read this posts:

[Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894234/stop-location-listener-in-android)

[Post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012870/android-how-to-stop-gps)

[Post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738980/gps-location-listener-stop)

[Post4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333237/turn-off-gps-icon-when-locationlistener-is-sleeping)